# Why is rack recommended for one Heroku web dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra, rack

I have a site with some static content.  It contains a few pages, css, javascript, and images.  I'd like to host this on Heroku for free, which I see I can do with their one web dyno plan.  My question is, why do their docs suggest rack for hosting static content on a single web dyno?  What are the problems you'd encounter with running Rails or Sinatra on one web dyno?  And does using rack only somehow solve these problems?

Comment: I think they recommend rack because it's more lightweight for static content?

Comment: Yeah, but what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Can you link to the doc page that recommends Rack so we can look at the context? It doesn't seem likely that they'd recommend Rack for static content (or Rack in general instead of a "Rack-based" framework like Sinatra/Rails)  since static content will just be served by Nginx and not even hit your stack. In other words, if you just have html/js/css/images and requests are hitting your stack, you're doing something wrong. My blog is a Rails app on Heroku that caches everything to .html files. Rails doesn't even need to boot up.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

Rails and Sinatra are both rack-based, so if you just have static content (like seriously just .html pages), then using bare-bones rack works very well.

I put a sample repository over at https://github.com/jwo/rack-static-sample

The idea is your rackup file (config.ru) just simply responds with a file in your public directory (this version is just a single index.html)

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/stylesheets", "/images"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for why it "works very well".  And why the others don't work very well.

Comment: Sinatra and Rails will work. But you add complexity and load time with Sinatra, and then more with Rails. So more of your time is spent inside of the frameworks. With Rack, you are "closer to the metal" so you're more IO bound than CPU bound.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended because its the "simplest" solution for the problem.  Why use a Rails or Sinatra framework which will be processing the incoming requests through hundreds/thousands of lines of code, if there is nothing for that code to do.

However, if you are wanted to host a static site, I would highly recommend any of AWS S3, Github Pages or Google Drive over Heroku.  The single dyno plan on Heroku might be free, but thats because it will idle after a time, and won't be costing them resources.  The first request into an idled dyno tends to take an extra 5-15 seconds.